# How can I sort each row of the 2d numpy-array by another 2d index-array?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have:

```
arr = np.array[[10 30 20],
               [30 20 10]]

indices = np.array[[2 1 0],
                   [2 1 0]]
```

I want:

```
[[20 30 10],
 [10 20 30]]
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[10, 30, 20],
               [30, 20, 10]])

indices = np.array([[2, 1, 0],
                   [2, 1, 0]])


res = np.take_along_axis(arr, indices, axis=1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[20 30 10]
 [10 20 30]]
```